# Lync 2010 - Scroll bar in my right dragging up automatically during chat

Tags: lync-2010

I am using Microsoft Lync 2010 for communication in my work place. I got this weird problem in the middle, before that it was working fine.

While chatting with my friends, We usually press Alt+Tab to switch over to the screens. When I do like that, the chat is automatically getting scrolled up a bit making me to scroll down each and every time When I want to see the recent messages.

Let me know, if you want further explanation on this.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance!!.

Comment: The real problem is : When I adjust my screen size by reducing its width, the scroll bar is going bit up automatically and setting it as a default position. So whenever I chat, the cursor is always a bit up.

Solution I found out is to close and open the chat again. Let me know, If there any other possibilities

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be fixed, because anytime Microsoft or Skype support are asked about it, they state it is a feature. they claim it's so you know where you left off reading and when you get back you can scroll down reading all of the messages and don't miss anything.

See [this link](https://community.skype.com/t5/Skype-Idea-Exchange/quot-Autoscroll-chats-quot-feature/idi-p/752534) for an example of Skype support saying this. (Lync is also Skype for Business)

Comment: Thanks. Its is acceptable that when you come back the cursor needs to be in the unread messages. But say for example, after that I read all the messages after the conversation is going for some 100 messages, then why does it replicating the same behavior when I don't have any messages to be read.